# How to display item in SPGridView in the order they are stored using ListTool > Items > Change Item Order

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint link list.I am programattically displaying items of the link list in the SPGridView.

I am using following code to read the list

```
SPList spList = myWeb.Lists["MyListNameHere"];
```

and assign the SpList as the datasource of SPGridView which display items as is.

But i want to display items in SPGridView in the same order as they are set through List Tool > Items > Change Item Order

Order of SPGridView items should always reflect the current order set in the link list items.

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is stored in a hidden column named Order.
Use SPDataSource control as your data source, set the listID to your list and set the select query to something like:

```
   <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name="Order" />
   </OrderBy>
```

That should do it